# UIImageView allows button beneath it to be touched

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Am developing an iPhone App. When the user taps a button, displaying a semi-transparent UIImageView on a page (i.e. covering the whole page). Now, since the UIImageView is semi-transparent, the buttons beneath it are seen. Clicking on the buttons (though the UIImageView is on top of it) is causing the button-click to be  processed ; but I want to stop this. When the UIImageView is on th e top, only touching UIImageView (which calls a method) should work ; touching anything beneath it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following alternatives :
First make sure that UIImageView is on top of button. Bring if front by using bringSubviewToFront

1. You can disable userInteraction of UIImageView.
2. If you have any action associated with UIImageView , then you can prefer UIButton over there instead of UIImageView and set your image as a background of UIButton , and add action you required to perform with this button.

Comment: Thank you! This is what worked finally! Adding a button (with its image set), rather than using a UIImageView

Comment: Not working for me. Same thing is happening in case of button also.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose yourImageView is your UIImageView above your button, do this,

```
[yourImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_semi_transparent_ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UIView on the click of a button and then add UIImageview as a subview of view. Then decrease the alpha of uiview.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you will add your semi-transparent imageView not to self.view but to your application's window. like this:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (Appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.window addSubview:yourImageView];
```

To remove yourImageView just use

```
[yourImageView removeFromSuperView];
```

Answer (score -1):

Hide and disable the buttons when the ImageView is shown:

```
[button setEnabled:NO]; // If you want the button not to respond
[button setHidden:YES]; // If you want the button not to be seen
```